# Xdebug not working over Drush

Tags: drush

I'm using Drupal VM and the Drush Launcher (0.6.0). Whenever I try to Xdebug, PhpStorm notices, but it never actually reaches my Drush command. It stops at running Drush. This seems to have started recently.

My command looks like:

```
XDEBUG_CONFIG="remote_enable=On remote_connect_back=Off remote_host=192.168.90.1" PHP_IDE_CO
NFIG="serverName=example.wizonesolutions.com" drush -l example.com module:custom-command
```

Answer (score 8):

From https://github.com/drush-ops/drush-launcher#xdebug-compatibility:

> Drush Launcher, like Composer automatically disables Xdebug by default. This improves performance substantially. You may override this feature by setting an environment variable. `DRUSH_ALLOW_XDEBUG=1 drush [command]`

So to make Xdebug reach the rest of your code, add `DRUSH_ALLOW_XDEBUG=1` to the environment variables in front of your command.

Comment: Would you mind editing to tag with ddev as well, maybe also mention how to do it in ddev web container? You don't need all that `XDEBUG_CONFIG="remote_enable=On remote_connect_back=Off remote_host=192.168.90.1" PHP_IDE_CO
NFIG="serverName=example.wizonesolutions.com" drush -l example.com module:custom-command` in general do you? Just the remote_anable=On?

Comment: This one isn't ddev, as it was a Drupal VM setup. So I did need that, as it doesn't work the same way :)